# How do I delete files from the Ubuntu One server

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

My system has crashed and I have had to rebuild it from local data backup storage.

I can't seem to re link my folders to u1 so want to clear the data on the servers so I can start over.

Obviously the original sources are no longer.

Can I clear the account or do I start a new one with an alternate email addy?

Matt

Answer (score 1):

You can stop syncing folders via the web interface at https://one.ubuntu.com/files/.

Simply press the **more** button on the right hand side and choose *Stop syncing this folder* when it shows up.

[image: Ubuntu One files web interface]